# c# How to get session from asp.net session cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state, session-cookies

I'm pretty basic with .net

But basically I've been told that to have session stickiness for my website in the environment it is to be deployed means I have to get session from the cookie `ASP.NET_SessionId`

But what does this mean/how do I use this?

And where I am using my existing session code e.g. `Session.Add("Something", something)` do I now need to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is automated for you

You don't have to manually read cookies yourself. Asp.net does it for you. So whenever you access `Session` dictionary your session will already be preserved if it existed from your previous request(s). If there is none (or expired) it will also be automatically created so adding items to it will make it work without a problem.

So basically instead of accessing Session identifier from a cookies and do whatever with it (as you won't be able to access intrinsic session store), just use `Session`:

```
Session["SomeKey"] = myVar;
// or
Session.Add("SomeKey", myVar);
```

and for reading

```
var o = Session["SomeKey"];
```

### Are cookies mandatory?

Basically Asp.net supports other means of session ID storage apart from cookies. You can enable cookieless session if you wanted to (a setting in `web.config` file). Session identifier will be added to your URL like:

```
http://www.example.com/(S(lit3py55t21z5v55vlm25s55))/orderform.aspx
```

Read more about it [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).

### What's the default?

By default session identifier is preserved in cookies. That means that you don't have to change anything in `web.config`. But if you'd like to use other means you'd have to set that in `web.config` (check the same upper link as before).

Comment: So the fact I have been told to use the cookie ASP.NET_SessionId doesnt *really* mean anything regarding configuration etc in the web.config. I just use the session as I normally would?

Comment: @asn1981: Yes. That's true. Only read cookie value when you need to know it for some other reasons. Otherwise just use `Session` and that's it. So don't listen to admins. They obviously haven't developed much on Asp.net ;)

Comment: Excellent thanks... Although Ryan Emerle answer was also helpful.

Comment: @asn1981: Yes Ryan answered your question in his last paragraph. But Ryan answered a more complex question though. He mainly talks about sessions on web farms and how to configure them if you use multiple web servers. I don't think that was actually what you've been asking about. Or was it?

Answer (score 0):

Typically the way that I use session variables in ASP.NET is like this

```
// set
Session["SessionVariableName"] = localVariable;

// get
localVariable = Session["SessionVariableName"] as LocalType; // then check nulls
```

The issue with any sessions is that if you don't go out of your way to change it, the default stores sessions in-proc so every time IIS recycles a worker process your session is lost. This can be easily fixed by using the built-in ASP.NET State Service. A quick search turned up [this](http://faisalsikder.wordpress.com/2010/05/08/using-the-asp-dot-net-state-service-for-state-management-in-asp-net-among-several-server/) article on using it.

Comment: InProc is OK in most cases. Using state service is not something you should be doing by default. If you really want to prevent users from losing their session you should prevent IIS from (having the need to) recycling your worker process.

Comment: But I've been told by the admins that to maintain session stickiness I need to use the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie. How do I use that?

Comment: @thekip In a webfarm, a state server is required, and its much easier to setup an ASP.NET State Server than to have everything pushed in to an SQL Server.

Comment: a webfarm is one of the reasons for using state server but I don't read anything about a webfarm anywhere. InProc is the fastest way of keeping sessions so until there's a compelling reason not to use it I would never advise otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a reference to the current session in multiple ways but the most easy way is just use the session property on the page.

See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.session.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
// Set
Session["mySession"] = "Hello World";

// Get
var s = Session["mySession"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Session stickiness is not a feature of ASP.net, but rather of a load balancer that may sit in front of it.  If you are using [`InProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) sessions, then the session data is stored in the server's memory.  With "sticky" sessions, the load balancer will send all requests from the same source (based on IP usually) to the same server to ensure that the session always exists.

This isn't the most scalable way to handle a web farm scenario.  Microsoft introduced two other mechanisms, `StateServer` and `SqlServer` which serve to send the session data to a single location for all web front ends.

You likely just need to make sure you don't have `cookieless` set to `true` in your [configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx).

Regardless of how this is all configured, you will always retrieve your session data the same way - ASP.NET abstracts the details away.